# How to delete a file after it was streamed in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to delete a temporary file after returning it form action. How can i achieve that with ASP.NET Core:

```
public IActionResult Download(long id)
{
    var file = "C:/temp/tempfile.zip";
    var fileName = "file.zip;
    return this.PhysicalFile(file, "application/zip", fileName);
    // I Would like to have File.Delete(file) here !!
}
```

The file is too big for returning using memory stream.

Comment: What is the size of the file? If it's a small one you can save the contents to the MemoryStream and delete the file in the same request once you load the file in the memorystream.

Comment: @AntoniosKatopodis unfortunately too big, it can be several hundreds of megabytes.

Comment: The whole point of a temp file is that it's, you know, temporary by nature. Still if you want to explicitly clean up after yourself, the best course is to queue it to be deleted by a background job at a later time. However, this smells of an XY problem. Where is this temp file coming from in the first place? Perhaps it would be better to create it in memory and send it to the user directly? Then there would be no file to clean up at all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[File()](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L1120) or [PhysicalFile()](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L1581) return a `FileResult`-derived class that just [delegates processing](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/PhysicalFileResult.cs) to an executor service. `PhysicalFileResult`'s [ExecuteResultAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/PhysicalFileResult.cs#L70) method calls :

```
var executor = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                 .GetRequiredService<IActionResultExecutor<PhysicalFileResult>>();
return executor.ExecuteAsync(context, this);
```

All other FileResult-based classes work in a similar way.

The [PhysicalFileResultExecutor](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/PhysicalFileResultExecutor.cs) class essentially writes the file's contents to the Response stream.

A quick and dirty solution would be to create your own `PhysicalFileResult`-based class that delegates to PhysicalFileResultExecutor but deletes the file once the executor finishes :

```
public class TempPhysicalFileResult : PhysicalFileResult
{
    public TempPhysicalFileResult(string fileName, string contentType)
                 : base(fileName, contentType) { }
    public TempPhysicalFileResult(string fileName, MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType)
                 : base(fileName, contentType) { }

    public override async  Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        try {
            await base.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
        }
        finally {
            File.Delete(FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of calling `PhysicalFile()` to create the `PhysicalFileResult` you can create and return a `TempPhysicalFileResult`, eg :

```
return new TempPhysicalFileResult(file, "application/zip"){FileDownloadName=fileName};
```

That's the same thing [PhysicalFile()](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L1581) does :

```
[NonAction]
public virtual PhysicalFileResult PhysicalFile(
    string physicalPath,
    string contentType,
    string fileDownloadName)
    => new PhysicalFileResult(physicalPath, contentType) { FileDownloadName = fileDownloadName };
```

A more sophisticated solution would be to create a custom executor that took care eg of compression as well as cleaning up files, leaving the action code clean of result formatting code

Comment: I would be careful with this if you are using streaming, this is fine for downloading a file, but if you are streaming and using ranges then it wont behave as expected.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a `FileStream` that deletes the underlying file as soon as the stream is closed. With the option `DeleteOnClose`.
As the stream is closed automatically after download, the file is deleted.

```
var fileStream = new FileStream(
    Path.GetTempFileName(),
    FileMode.Create, 
    FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
    FileShare.Read, 
    4096, 
    FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);

// add something to the file

fileStream.Position = 0;

return File(fileStream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But could you elaborate on the reason why fileStream.Position needs to be set to zero? I see that without this line response keeps going infinitely but I am wondering why is that the case? How does it work?

Comment: When adding content to the stream, the Position is used to keep track of the end of the stream. When switching from writing to reading it has to be reset.

Comment: Note that this only works if the file is actually downloaded. If the user clicks "Cancel" on the download prompt, the file will _not_be deleted. I do not know whether this is different with the other solutions, though...

Answer (score 1):

Since the file is big one solution is to send a token (like a guid) along side the request. Only once the download has been completed you want to delete the file (otherwise you risk losing it). So using that token the client will make a new request using the aforementioned token. So you will know that the download was successful and that you can proceed to delete the file.

I suggest using a Dictionary to map a token to a file.

Deleting on one request seems like a bad practice due to the fact that you can easily lose the file.

Also you can use Henk Mollema answer to be certain that all files are cleared periodically if that is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to do this within the same request as the requests ends directly after the streaming is complete. A better option might be to run a timed background task [via a hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2) which periodically removes all files (e.g. with a last write time of >5 minutes ago) from the temp directory.

Answer (score -1):

You can load content of file. delete file and send content in response. in MVC you can return a file in response. check the snippet below

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    var fileName = $"client-file-name.ext";
    var filepath = $"filepath";
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
    //delete file here
    return File(fileBytes, "application/x-msdownload", fileName);
}
```

Comment: The question says “The file is too big for returning using memory stream.”, so reading it into memory would not work here. As long as that is not an issue, reading it into memory is a fine solution of course.