# OutOfMemoryException when using WriteRecords with .NET 5 ASPNET

Tags: c#, .net-core, out-of-memory, large-files, streamwriter

We have an endpoint that loads records from the database and creates a CSV from the records and then returns the file stream. But when the records are greater than 200K, we get OutOfMemoryException.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Export()
    {
        var records = // get all records from the database
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
        var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        await csvWriter.WriteRecordsAsync(records);
        csvWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Flush();
        memoryStream.Flush();
        string filename = $"Records_{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")}.csv";
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return File(memoryStream, "text/csv", filename);
    }
```

Is there a better way of doing this to prevent OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: As you buffer the result in memory, you surely can run out of memory. You may want to write the result to a temporary file instead, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54901479/how-to-delete-a-file-after-it-was-streamed-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score -2):

I dont know why you are getting this error. but from my below code, I am able to read large size of data, I tested with 3Gb approx data. What is your data size?

Here is my code using CSV helper.

```
private IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>> ReadCSV(Stream source, IEnumerable<TableField> cols)
        {
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(source, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var cache = new TypeConverterCache();
                cache.AddConverter<float>(new CSVSingleConverter());
                cache.AddConverter<double>(new CSVDoubleConverter());
                var csv = new CsvReader(reader,
                    new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    {
                        Delimiter = ";",
                        HasHeaderRecord = true,
                        CultureInfo = global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        TypeConverterCache = cache
                    });
                csv.Read();
                csv.ReadHeader();
                var map = (
                        from col in cols
                        from src in col.Sources()
                        let index = csv.GetFieldIndex(src, isTryGet: true)
                        where index != -1
                        select new { col.Name, Index = index, Type = col.DataType }).ToList();

                while (csv.Read())
                {
                    yield return map.ToDictionary(
                        col => col.Name,
                        col => EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject(csv.GetField(col.Type, col.Index)));
                }
            }
        }
```