# Creating a zip file and return it to client for download

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm making a .NET Core 7 MVC project, I have an endpoint that I call with a fetch from the front that should get some files from the server zip them and return them.

So far I have this

```cs
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadPDFs(string jobId)
{
    var selectedFiles = _requestsManager.GetPDFsZipFromJobId(jobId);

    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    using var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);

    foreach (var pdfFile in selectedFiles)
    {
        if (pdfFile != string.Empty)
        {
            var entry = archive.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(pdfFile));

            using var entryStream = entry.Open();
            using var pdfFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(pdfFile);

            pdfFileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
        }
    }
    //UPDATE 1
    archive.Dispose();
    //
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream)
    };

    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = $"{jobId}_PDFs.zip"
    };

    return response;
}
```

This gets me a file with some data I see it's size not 0, but I can't open it, when I try with WinRAR I get

> the archive is either in unknown format or damaged

This is the javascript for sending the request

```js
function handlePDFsBatch() {
    fetch("/Engine/DownloadPDFs")
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) return response.blob();
            else if (response.status === 404) throw new Error("File not found.");
            else throw new Error("Unexpected error.");
        })
        .then((blob) => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            const a = document.createElement("a");
            a.style.display = "none";
            a.href = url;
            a.download = `${crntJobId}.zip`;
            document.body.appendChild(a);

            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error downloading file:", error);
        });
}
```

***UPDATE 1***
The code for creating a zip file is working correctly and making a valid zip file, I tried it on a console app and saved it to the disk.
So the problem is either in sending the file or receiving it.

***UPDATE 2*** Solved here is a working code.

```cs
public MemoryStream GetZipStream(List<string> files)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {

        foreach (var pdfFile in files)
        {
            if (pdfFile != string.Empty)
            {
                var entry = archive.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(pdfFile));

                using var entryStream = entry.Open();
                using var pdfFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(pdfFile);

                pdfFileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
            }
        }
    }

    return memoryStream;
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DownloadPDFs(string jobId)
{
     var selectedFiles = _requestsManager.GetPDFsNamesFromJobId(jobId);

     var memoryStream = _requestsManager.GetZipStream(selectedFiles);

     memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

     return File(memoryStream, "application/zip", $"{jobId}_PDFs.zip");
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
fetch("/Engine/DownloadPDFs")
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) return response.blob();
        else throw new Error('Failed to fetch the file');
    })
    .then(blob => startDownload(blob))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error downloading file:", error);
    });

function startDownload(blob) {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'PDFs.zip';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

Comment: ASP.NET Core actions return `IActionResult` not `HttpResponseMessage`. All the code after `memoryStream.Seek` should be replaced with `return File(memoryStream,"application/zip","MyZip.zip")`. The [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-7.0) method allows specifying other settings too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC and Web API actions return `IActionResult` or `IResult` objects, not HttpResponseMessage. All the code after `memoryStream.Seek` should be replaced with `return File(memoryStream,"application/zip","MyZip.zip")`, eg:

```
Stream PackageFiles(IEnumerable<string> files)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    using(var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var pdfFile in files)
        {
            if (pdfFile != string.Empty)
            {
                var entry = archive.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(pdfFile));

                using var entryStream = entry.Open();
                using var pdfFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(pdfFile);

                pdfFileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
            }
        }
    }
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return memoryStream;

}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DownloadPDFs(string jobId)
{
    var selectedFiles = _requestsManager.GetPDFsZipFromJobId(jobId);

    var archiveStream= PackageFiles(selectedFiles)
    return File(archiveStream,"application/zip",$"PDFs_for_{jobId}.zip")
}
```

The [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-7.0) can return an [ETag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) and [Last-Modified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) header too.

If the PDFs are stored in a specific folder, the entire `PackageFiles` method can be replaced by [ZipArchive.CreateFromDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.createfromdirectory?view=net-7.0) :

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DownloadPDFs(string jobId)
{
    ...
    var tempPath=$"path_to_temp/PDFs_for_{jobId}.zip";
    ZipArchive.CreateFromDirectory(jobFilePath,
        tempPath,
        CompressionLevel.SmallestSize,
        false);

    var archiveStream= PackageFiles(selectedFiles)
    return File(tempPath,"application/zip",$"PDFs_for_{jobId}.zip")
}
```

The temporary file won't be deleted automatically. You'll have to clean up the temporary folder periodically, or use a custom FileResult object [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903994/134204) that deletes the temporary file at the end